# How to sum of price in jquery after Append raw in a table and show all price in a id named sub_total

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a module where if I click on a product item it will add cart list by append method. after appending any item the price of each append item will summation. and then show this result of summation on another id such as an id name **sub_total**

Here is my append code

```js
$('#selectedMenu').append('<tr class="menu-row"><td><input type="text" class="price no-style" name="menu_price[]" id="menu_price" value="' + data.price + '"><input type="hidden" id="menu_hidden_price" value="' + data.price +'"></td><td><span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="cancel fa fa-times"></i></span></td></tr>');
```

after append take all price by class named **price** and sum all price

```
   $(document).on('click ready keyup change', '.price', function(){
        var sum = 0;

        $('.price').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });

         $('#sub_total').val(sum);
    });
```

The summation result will show on an input filed which is defined by an id named **sub_total**

```
    <table class="table order-bill">
           <tr>
                <th>Sub Total</th>
                 <td><input type="text" value="0.00" class="no-style" id="sub_total"></td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <th>Total</th>
               <td><input type="text" value="0.00" class="no-style" id="total_price"></td>
            </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to sum of price in jquery after Append raw in a table and show all price in a id named sub_total

Comment: @BelalKhan look at specification of `.each` if index is equal to length of `.price` elements - 1 than `$('#sub_total').val(sum);`

Comment: `$('#sub_total').val(sum);` here is no problem @Zydnar, I have solved my problem now. My problem was in the jquery event.

Comment: @BelalKhan In this case I suggest you to answer this question by yourself to make it closed.

Answer (score 1):

I create a function and call this function in the event which event is append the following raw.

```js
function summationMenyPrice() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.price').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('#sub_total').val(sum);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the css selector, you should use the class of the product container

```
$(document).on('click ready keyup change', '.price', function(){
```

Change it to

```
$(document).on('click ready keyup change', '.<CONTAINER-CLASS-HERE>', function(){
```